# Ubuntu 12.04 does not suspend with proprietary driver for Radeon 6800

Tags: radeon, fglrx, catalyst

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 (though these issues have existed in previous releases too) and have a Radeon 6800 graphics card. I've run into issues with the open-source driver (the system would randomly hang when shutting down) so I switched to the proprietary driver (I compiled it myself using [these instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29)), but I am having new problems now.

The main issue is that when I go into sleep mode, about 50-75% of the time, the screen goes black but the monitor does not actually shut off, and I can hear that the fans/hard drive are not suspending either. I can't get the computer to wake up (Ctrl+Alt+F1,2,3,etc. does not work), and I always end up force shutting down with the power button.

I'd *really* appreciate help! Here is some information that might be helpful:

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series  
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11631 Compatibility Profile Context

$ dmesg | grep fglrx
[...]
[    6.718606] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 8.96.4 [Apr  5 2012] with 1 minors
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the instructions you used specifically this line

> sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg
>   Ubuntu/oneiric

You state you are running 12.04 Precise but the instructions you used are for oneiric Ubuntu 11.10.

Please review the accepted answer [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers) for the correct method to install catalyst on 12.04.  You may need to purge some of your install before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this works properly with Catalyst 12.6 (released yesterday)!

Comment: What evidence do you have to back this up  - please share. catalyst 12.6 is a beta release